# Facing Login Loop in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: login, login-screen

All of sudden started facing Login Loop.
I tried upgrading packages via tty still no luck.

Tried `startx` via tty3 and it's success but too irresponsive.

Tried chown `.xauthority` file with username. Still no luck.

How to fix this login loop issue?

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Comment: Will this help you: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop/

Comment: @ldias No buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Method 3 in this article](https://letsfoss.com/ubuntu-20-04-login-loop-fix/) worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and tried all the things you did. The culprit turned out to be a very long environment variable. My `LS_COLORS` env var was over 9000 characters long as is was generated from a `dircolors` database. As soon as I removed it I could log in again. In `/var/log/syslog` I was getting a segfault in `libpcre.so.3.13.3`. That env var must have been causing gdm to crash.

Comment: Show the env variables with `printenv` and use `unset LS_COLORS` to remove it. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you see a line like

```
gnome-session-b[2118]: segfault at 7fff86f37ff0 ip 00007f5eff18812f sp 00007fff86f37ff8 error 6 in libpcre.so.3.13.3[7f5eff173000+51000]
```

in `dmesg` output or in `/var/log/syslog`, this is a [known bug in the pcre3 package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcre3/+bug/1818027). It apparently is triggered by overly long environment variables.

@PaulNetherwood reported a large `LS_COLORS` variable; for me it was `PATH` suddenly exceeding 8192 characters in length.

To work around the problem, you need to find the overly long variable(s) and shorten (or completely undefine) it. This finds all exported variables with values longer than 8192 characters:

```
$ env | awk -F= 'length($0) - length($1) > 8192'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the first result on Google, so thought to throw in what helped me. I found out the entire home directory of the user was owned by a user called "systemd-coredump".
I simply did chown -R user:user /home/user