# Ubuntu 20.04.2 login loop due to segmentation fault in libpcre.so.3.13.3

Tags: bash, login, segmentation-fault

Out of sudden I got this login loop issue in my laptop. From `var/log/syslog` I can able to find out it is segfault issue

`gnome-session-b[2739]: segfault at 7ffe34d8xx50 ip 00007ffe34d8dxxx error 6 in libpcre.so.3.13.3[7f49d37dxx00+51000]`

But don't know the exact reason for this. From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236602/facing-login-loop-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa) it says due to LS_COLORS environment variable.

How can I remove this environment variable ? Does doing this will cause any negative impacts on my system ?

As a workaround, I created a added a new user and copied all my contents to the new user. And I am able to login to my new user without any problems. Don't know how its working in new user but not in the old one.

Ubuntu version: `20.04.2 LTS, focal`

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facing Login Loop in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236602/facing-login-loop-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa)

Comment: It isn't necessarily the `LS_COLORS` environment variable; any variable could have become too long (for me it was `PATH`). In the question you've linked to, I've added some more troubleshooting information and a link to the official bug, and I've flagged your question as a duplicate of it.

Comment: I think the `LS_COLORS` setup is non-standard, it's likely found somewhere in your configuration (like `~/.bashrc`), and you probably did not copy it (or not fully), so it did not apply to your new user. That variable in particular just sets up highlighting for the `ls` command, so if you're not missing anything there, you should be fine :-)